# How to solve $42x = 47 \pmod{101}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

Does anyone know how I can solve this question?
Since $101$ is a prime number, I can't figure out where to begin.
$$x = \frac{47}{42} \pmod{101} \ldots ?$$

Thanks!

Comment: This is your second (perhaps the third) elementary number theory question that can be solved with the extended Euclidean algorithm. That suggests you try it first for modular arithmetic problems. Then ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $a\equiv101-a\pmod{101}$ you get $$42x\equiv-54\pmod{101}$$
Now dividing by $6$ (we can because $\gcd(6,101)=1$) we get $$7x\equiv-9\pmod{101}\\-94x\equiv 92\pmod{101}\\-47x\equiv 46\pmod{101}\\54x\equiv 46\pmod{101}\\27x\equiv 23\pmod{101}\\27x\equiv-78\pmod{101}\\9x\equiv-26\pmod{101}\\9x\equiv 75\pmod{101}\\3x\equiv 25\pmod{101}$$
Now since for $x=34$ we have $3x\equiv 1\pmod{101}$ then for $x=34\cdot 25$ we have $3x\equiv 25\pmod{101}$ while $34\cdot 25=17\cdot 50=850$ and $850\equiv 42\pmod{101}$ hence $x\equiv 42\pmod{101}$ is the solution to $42x\equiv 47\pmod{101}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint. By using the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Procedure), find two integers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$42a-101b=1.$$ 
Then 
$$47a=(42a)x=(1+101b)x\equiv x \pmod{101}.$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Use the extended Euclidean algorithm for $\gcd(42,101)$ to find $a$ such that $42a \equiv 1 \bmod 101$.

Alternatively, note that $42= 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7$ and find the inverses of $2,3,7 \bmod 101$, which are probably easy by inspection.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is equivalent to find to integers $x,k$ such that 
$$42x + 101k = 47.$$
Using Euclid's algorithm:
$$101 = 42\cdot 2+17$$
$$42 = 17\cdot2+8$$
$$17 = 8\cdot2+1$$
which gives $$1 = 101\cdot5+42\cdot(-12).$$
Now multiply by $47$:
$$47 = 101(235)+42(-564).$$
So $x = -564 \mod 101 = 42 \mod 101.$

Answer (score 1):

$$42x = 47 \pmod{101} \implies (42x + 47) \equiv 0 \pmod{101}$$
This implies that

$$101\,\big|\,42\cdot x\,$$
Therefore

> $$x = \{101\cdot a \, \big| \,\forall\, a \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$42\cdot 42=1764=17\cdot 101 +47$$